# Still image within variable height div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with variable height, this height is changed via javascript, I need to keep the image inside it always fixed in the footer.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $(".content").append("<br><br>Appended text</b>");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid" style="background:url('https://place-hold.it/2000x700');background-size:cover;">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-8 col-8 content"> 
        testestestestestestestestestestestestestestestestestes
        testestestestestestestestestestestestestestes
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-4 slide_home_person" style="">
     <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100/111/fff.png/000" class="slide_image_person" width="100%">
    </div>   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<button id="btn1">Append text</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sNniffer/7zLeuhjm/2/

Comment: It;s already done, you have to give only position absolute to ('.slide_image_person') class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add property `position: absolute` to the the class `slide_image_person`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $(".content").append("<br><br>Appended text</b>");
  });
});
```

```css
.slide_image_person {
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-8 content">    
        testestestestestestestestestestestestestestestestestes
        testestestestestestestestestestestestestestes
            </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-4 slide_home_person" style="">
                    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100/111/fff.png/000" class="slide_image_person" width="100%">
                </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="btn1">Append text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: absolute;` to CSS

```
.slide_image_person {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```